# Unable to get db response for update query for further execution in go

Tags: database, go, response

I want to update data in remote db table and do further tasks but could not do it.

Using same code with insert query, I am able to insert values in same table where I am getting response very fast and going ahead for further tasks.
But in update query it does update values in table but could not going further.

Here is my sample code that I have tried:

```
package src

import (
    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

const (
    DB_NAME = "test_db"
    DB_HOST = "remote db ip address:port"
    DB_USER = "username"
    DB_PASS = "password"
)

const (
    bufferSize int    = 1024
    port       string = ":23456"
)

func main() {

    udpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp6", port)

    var s Server
    s.conn, err = net.ListenUDP("udp4", udpAddr)

    fmt.Println("Trying to connect remote db")

    dsn := DB_USER + ":" + DB_PASS + "@" + DB_HOST + "/" + DB_NAME + "?charset=utf8"
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    fmt.Println("Connected db")

    rows, err := db.Query("UPDATE user_name_table SET user_id = ? WHERE user_name = ? ", "abcd", "admin")
    defer rows.Close()

    if err != nil {

        log.Fatal(err)
        fmt.Println("error in updating values")

    } else {

        fmt.Println("updated successfully in db")

    }

    // not coming here for doing further tasks

}
```

Also , I have tried to update db table from php webservice and its working fine but using go neither its giving response after updating values nor moving further.

Please help me .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution.Just removed unwanted rows for returned response for updating query and everything working fine again.

```
_, err := db.Query("UPDATE user_name_table SET user_id = ? WHERE user_name = ? ",   "abcd", "admin")
    // defer rows.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `log.Fatal(err)` will call `os.Exit(1)`. In other words, it will terminate your program when `err != nil`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But, here I'm not getting any error.Query does update values in database after that it does not go ahead.